# Проблема при изменении font-weight input на bold

Tags: css, input

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Поля логин и пароль меняют размер, когда ставлю стиль `font-weight:bold`.

Как этого избежать?

[image: проблема font-weight:bold]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно задать им фиксированную ширину. Этого хватит.